# Access VBA control reference issue?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to loop through all the controls on an Access form but for some reason the controls object is not giving me the correct properties.
When I select and right click on "Control" (in 'As Control') it says "identifier under cursor is not recognized".

I'm thinking it's a reference issue but I can't figure what's missing or incorrect. I don't get any syntax error so Control is a valid object.

I tried decompiling, repair and compacting just to be sure.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic [control object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.control) doesn't have too many useful properties or methods.

It covers also things like lines or subform containers or tab cards, which don't have much in common.

The specific controls like [Textboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox) have all the properties you are probably looking for.

You still can loop over all controls, and set the usual properties that most controls have, like `.Visible` or `.Locked`. Even if Intellisense doesn't provide them.

`ctl.Locked = bLocked` will work.

But you should handle (`On Error Goto`) or ignore (`On Error Resume Next`) runtime errors that will occur, if one control doesn't have the property you want to set.

---

Bonus question to everyone: why does the generic control object have the `.Dropdown` method that applies only to combo boxes? Very strange.

Comment: Thank you. 

That's confusing that it wouldn't be in intellisense yet still be valid.